# Why my `class="modal"` does not work but when i use `class="collapse"` it works

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

the output is always fade but the modal/form doesn't show.

This is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" type="text/css" />`

<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<li><button  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Add</button></li>


<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
    ...sadsadsadsadsada
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think is necessary more context, because trying your code here, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/t0uskfbs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the id of the modal, remember the button target the modal by it's id:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"...
```

Comment: i tried that code using id ? but it doesnt work it fades in but the form doesn't show , but if i use class="collapse" it works i don't know what is wrong with my code . BTW thankyou

Comment: You're right, i just tried your code in JSFiddle and it works fine.